# Как узнать что std::string реалоцировался?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2017

Как узнать что std::string реалоцировался ?

Comment: Практически - наверное, сравнивать возвращаемый `c_str()` указатель... Теоретически - никак.

Comment: написать свой аллокатор и подсунуть его строке. Все выделение памяти теперь будет под контролем

Comment: Там еще есть оптимизация коротких строк, когда перевыделения вообще не происходит.

Comment: есть ещё идея - смотреть в capacity - если оно поменялось, то скорее всего строка "реалоцировалась".